# Get specific text in HTML code using webbrowser and VB

Tags: html, vb.net

I want in VB using webbrowser somehow get text : **00:15** from this HTML code :

```
<div id="stop15" class="sec">

<div class="sec">00:15</div>

</div>
```

I tried :

```
Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")

For Each he As HtmlElement In elements

If he.OuterHtml.ToUpper.Contains("sec") Then

CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(he.GetAttribute("class"))
                      'or he.InnerText()

End If

Next
```

, but It does not work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: "can get the text 00:15 using InnerText, but I can't get it like a variable" -> I don't understand this statement. Can you please post the code you have tried to help us understand what might be the problem?

Comment: Pleas be more specific on the issue and what you tried to so far.

Comment: This is much better. I guess that you are calling this code from the DocumentCompleted method (to make sure that all the information has been read properly). Your implementation provides lots of information and thus if you have doubts about the exact property you are looking for, you should do a step-by-step execution: put your mouse over "he" (the one in For Each...) for each iteration and see the treeview with all the information, there you will be able to find the best way to define what you are after instead of doing a blind trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load page in vairable String
2. Use [regular expressions](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) to look at < div class="sec">.+< /div>
3. extract your text